# when we move to next field the validation message showing enter the previous field should appear?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have worked on this but nothing is working out seems a bit awkward.I have used the onfocus command also .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var field = $('input[type="text"]');
field.focus(function() { //Empty the field on focus
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr("value", "");
});

    field.blur(function() { //Check the field if it is left empty
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            //alert('This field can not be left empty');
            $(this).val(thisValue);
        }
    });
});​
```

I think i have missed out or mistaken a fieldname could you tell me where i went wrong.

Comment: can you be please more specific that what is the problem? maybe js fiddle. please describe what is awkward.

Comment: Also, this shouldn't be tagged as cakephp. It's a Javascript / jQuery problem.